# React state not updated and error "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an app that once a user logs in (enters a partyID), it directs them to a new page where it pulls back all the users data. Once they 'Log In; the new page isn't pulling the data as I expected.

However when I write to console the data is says undefined but the fetch URL does work when i go to it locally on my browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b48KQ.png)

Here is my code

```
class CalcForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
    };
}

 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    const serachByCustomerId = this.props.location.state;
    const url =
        "<MYURL>/api/Customer/" +
        serachByCustomerId;

    console.log("URL Being used ", url);
    fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => this.setState({ data: data }))

    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
        console.log("data after search", this.state.data);
    }
}

// renders to display on page
render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;
    // if page is loading displays loading text and spinner to make user awear
    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div className="pageLoading">
                <p>Loading...</p>
                <FadeLoader size={150} color={"#2d8259"} loading={isLoading} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div> hi </div>
    );
}

}
export default CalcForm;
```

I was expected the data returned to be printed into the console but upon looking I get undefined and there is also an error I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is asynchronous, so if you want to console.log the data, it must be within a callback:

```
this.setState({key: value}, () => {console.log(value})
```

This is what your componentDidMount() would look like:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.setState({isLoading: true });
const searchByCustomerId = this.props.location.state;
const url = "<MYURL>/api/Customer/" + searchByCustomerId;

console.log("URL Being used ", url);
fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => this.setState({data: data },
        () => {
            console.log("data after search", data);
            this.setState({isLoading: false})
          }
     ))
```

}

PLUS: you had a typo (search not serach)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not go down the hooks approach? Its far more nicer and easier to do things:

psuedo code to get you going. It has an await function so you should be able to derive your data once you pass in your url.

```
export default function CalcForm() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(false);

  const getData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    setData(response.json());
    setLoading(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="pageLoading">
        <p>Loading...</p>
        <FadeLoader size={150} color="#2d8259" loading={isLoading} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div className="pageLoading">hi</div>;
}
```